# How to setup dependent timers in swift?

Tags: swift

I have a timer that calls a function every second. However, I want to set up another timer that calls a function something around .3 of a second before. How would I set this up?

Answer (score 2):

It would be much easier to use your timer to call the other, earlier function. Then add code to call your other function 0.3 seconds later.

```
// Called every second by the timer
func someTimerHandler(timer: Timer) {
    // perform earlier function here

    // Use another queue if desired
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
        // perform later function here
    }
}
```